# Firebase Update Multiple Child value From Multiple Key for Specific Child Value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase database Structure.I am saving mobile no as child name. What I need to do is first get the `tBid` value for each key having specific mobile no value equal to `ok` then add/deduct a number and then update `tBid` value for all key under `b_ookk_node`

[image]

I have tried below code so far but it is not working.How can I achieve this

```
final String mobile_no = singleToneClass.getInstance().getData();

mDatabasebook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("b_ookk_node");
Query ref_book = mDatabase.child(mobile_no).equalTo("ok");

ref_book.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

            for (DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final int total_bid = Integer.parseInt(datas.child("tBid").getValue(String.class));
                String t_bid = Integer.toString(total_bid - 1);
                mDatabasebook.child("tBid").setValue(t_bid);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `b_ookk_node` in your code matches the struck out node in your JSON screenshot, this code looks OK. But it'd require you to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for each mobile number, since an index can only be defined on a property of which you specify the name. Since I assume the phone numbers are user-entered data, defining an index for each of them isn't feasible

In short: your current data structure allows your to easily look up the mobile number of a push ID, but not the push ID for a mobile number. To allow the latter you'll need to set up an additional data structure, which looks like this:

```
"number_to_pushid_map": {
  "096554885": {
    "-LyON1kEn...sWpW": true
    "-LyON1kEn...key2": true
  }
}
```

In this structure you can then look up the push ID for a number that the user entered.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

---

Aside from that:

- The `if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {` in your code is not needed. If there are no child nodes, then `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` will already return an empty iterator, and the loop will never be entered.
- Consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for the updating of the bid, as right now two users updating the bid around the same time may end up overwriting each other's result.
- Consider storing the `tBid` value as a number, instead of as a string, so that you don't have to constantly convert it back and forth.